# Входные параметры shell скрипта

Tags: unix, shell, sh

Подскажите почему не работает скрипт:

```
    #!/bin/sh

   for i in $#;
   do
     echo "hello"
   done
```

нужно чтобы скрипт выводил hello Столько раз сколько входных параметров ввёл юзер

То есть вот так:

```
./shhh 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

конструкция

```
for i in $#
```

в вашем примере эквивалентна конструкции

```
for i in 3
```

т.к. `$#` — это количество параметров, переданных скрипту.

понятно, что в таком варианте цикл выполнится только один раз.

---

для того, чтобы цикл выполнился (к примеру) три раза, надо указать **три** аргумента после ключевого слова `in`. например, так:

```
for i in 1 2 3
```

---

для того, чтобы получить такую последовательность аргументов (`1 2 ... n`, «от единицы до `n`»), обладая лишь значением `n`, можно воспользоваться, например, программой `seq`:

```
$ seq 1 3
1
2
3
```

ну а чтобы результат её выполнения подставить в качестве аргументов после ключевого слова `in`, надо «обернуть» эту команду в «подстановочную конструкцию» `$(...)`:

```
for i in $(seq 1 $#)
```

---

стоит отметить, что [стандартом posix предусмотрена](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) ещё одна форма «подстановочной конструкции»:

```
`...`
```

использовать эту форму, или форму `$(...)` — по большей части дело вкуса. но форму `$(...)` удобнее использовать во вложенных конструкциях типа `$(... $(...) ...)`